# How to control Music through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I'm curious to see if there's a simple way to control music through PowerShell.

I have Windows10, so Media Player doesn't really exist anymore.  My default music player is MediaMonkey, but in the HKLM it didn't really have anything obvious I could hook into.

I've found a couple pages that have hinted at a solution, but nothing is producing music.

This is the closest code I've seen so far:

```
    $PLAYER=NEW-OBJECT -ComObject 'Mediaplayer.Mediaplayer' 
    $PLAYER.Filename=$Filename
    $Player.Play()
```

but this doesn't play any music.

To find out what is available to me I ran this command:

`get-childitem | ? {$_.name -like "*MediaMonkey*"}`

and got:

```
         Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes
    Name                           Property                                                                                
    ----                           --------                                                                                
    MediaMonkey                    (default) : MediaMonkey Windows 7  Controller                                            
    MediaMonkey.APLFile            (default) : APL Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.ASXFile            (default) : ASX Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.CDAFile            (default) : CDA Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.FLAFile            (default) : FLA Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.ISMAFile           (default) : ISMA Audio File                                                             
    MediaMonkey.M3U8File           (default) : M3U8 Audio File                                                             
    MediaMonkey.M3UFile            (default) : M3U Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.M4BFile            (default) : M4B Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.MACFile            (default) : MAC Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.MMDCFile           (default) : MMDC Audio File                                                             
    MediaMonkey.MMIPFile           (default) : MediaMonkey Package File                                                    
    MediaMonkey.MP+File            (default) : MP+ Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.MP3File            (default) : MP3 Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.MPPFile            (default) : MPP Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.MPVFile            (default) : MPV Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.OGGFile            (default) : OGG Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.PLAFile            (default) : PLA Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.PLSFile            (default) : PLS Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.QTFile             (default) : QT Audio File                                                               
    MediaMonkey.VQFFile            (default) : VQF Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.WAVFile            (default) : WAV Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.WAXFile            (default) : WAX Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.WMAFile            (default) : WMA Audio File                                                              
    MediaMonkey.X-DIVXFile         (default) : X-DIVX Audio File                                                           
    MediaMonkey.XSPFFile           (default) : XSPF Audio File                                                             
    MediaMonkey.XVIDFile           (default) : XVID Audio File
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From [MediaMonky's Introduction to scripting page](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Introduction_to_scripting) (see the About external scripts and applications header):

> MediaMonkey exposes an API via the Microsoft COM model. This allows external applications to access and control MediaMonkey directly. These applications can be written in any language that can access COM objects.

PowerShell definitely qualifies.

Converting the VBScript example on that page, the code in PowerShell would be something like this:

```
$sdb = New-Object -ComObject SongsDB.SDBApplication
$sdb.ShutdownAfterDisconnect = $false
```

You'll have to play around with the object to find the properties/methods you need to control it, but it looks pretty straightforward.

Also see [Interaction with MediaMonkey from outside](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Scripting_Tips_%26_Tricks#Interaction_with_MediaMonkey_from_outside).

Comment: There is almost no documentation or code examples, I'm struggling to load a track :-). `$sdb.SelectFolder()` and `$sdb.Player.Play()` look promising...

Comment: @sodawillow I don't actually have MediaMonkey so I haven't tested it, but intellisense ought it to make it possible (if frustrating).

Comment: Windows media player also has a COM interface, don't remember the ProgId though.